# Bootstrap/KnockoutJS: img tag not honoring its height attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS and Bootstrap in ASP.NET MVC4 to display image thumbnails. The problem I have is the images, as one would expect, are different sizes. So, setting `span3` on the `li` element deals with the width issue, but then the height is not equal for all thumbs, so I tried setting that on the `img` tag.. however, this does not work and when I remove the span3 on the `li` and add width to the `img` tag, then I see the width is also not being honored. This is very strange beheaviour. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's my markup:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: images">
                <li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img data-bind="attr: { src: thumbnailUrl, alt: caption }" height="130px" />
                        <p data-bind="html: caption"></p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `height` overrides HTML `height` attribute. If you want a fixed height for your `img` try this CSS:

```
.your-img-selector {
    height: 130px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height attribute accepts only an integer number in pixels or percentage. Change it to `height="130"` or better use CSS.